# Bug in System.Random constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

The `System.Threading.ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue` method threw an exception the other day that took me totally by surprise.  Here's the stack trace:

```
System.OverflowException: Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid.
   at System.Math.AbsHelper(Int32 value)
   at System.Random..ctor(Int32 Seed)
   at System.Threading.Collections.ConcurrentQueue`1.TryDequeueCore(T& result)
   at System.Threading.Collections.ConcurrentQueue`1.TryDequeue(T& result)
   at MyProgram.ThreadProc() in c:\MyProgram\Main.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

At first I thought the problem was that `TryDequeueCore` called the `Random` constructor with a bad value.  But further investigation reveals that `TryDequeueCore` calls the default constructor.  It looks to me like the error is in the `Random` constructor:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       int32 System.Environment::get_TickCount()
  IL_0006:  call       instance void System.Random::.ctor(int32)
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Random::.ctor
```

As the documentation for the `System.Environment.TickCount` property says:

> The value of this property is derived
>   from the system timer and is stored as
>   a 32-bit signed integer. Consequently,
>   if the system runs continuously,
>   TickCount will increment from zero to
>   Int32..::.MaxValue for approximately
>   24.9 days, then jump to Int32..::.MinValue, which is a
>   negative number, then increment back
>   to zero during the next 24.9 days.

So, if you call the `Random` constructor during that one-millisecond period (after the system has been up for `int.MaxValue` milliseconds), it's going to throw this exception.

Does anybody have a workaround?  For my own code, I can make a `CreateRandom` method that gets the `TickCount` value and checks it for `int.MinValue`.  But what to do about code that I have no control over?

I hope the RTL team fixes this in .NET 4.0.

Update 2009/07/22: The BCL Team responded to the bug and said that it has been resolved for the next release.

Comment: I hope you made a bug report :)

Comment: Wow, nice investigation.

Comment: Bug reported at Microsoft Connect.  
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio
Bug #475447.

Comment: Actually, my bug report is #475446.  Somebody else reported it as 475447.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try`/`catch` and retry a millisecond later seems just about the only thing you can do until this bug does get fixed.

Comment: Perhaps.  But take the case of ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue.  That method isn't supposed to throw exceptions at all.  I now have to wrap all calls to TryDequeue in a try/catch block.  And what about code that I don't know uses Random?

Comment: As long as deep down in the system libraries there's a bug that causes exceptions to be thrown when one should never be, what else can you do with other code outside of your control, to which you have no sources, and which MIGHT call the system lib in question? Unless you can switch to an open-source stack, where you could fix errors once you find them, you're inevitably at the proprietary code supplier's mercy. try/catch is just about the only thing you can do, and it's definitely not perfect, but, what else?